# Is there a way to update ContactKey in Marketing Cloud using REST API?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

I know that I can delete Contacts using the REST API. I've just tested this and this works. This is a two step process.

Firstly you need to retrieve the Adapter objects, then you can use these objects to delete Contacts from All Contacts or MobileConnect. Refer to the following documentation:

Step 1. Get Delete Options

Step 2. Delete Contact(s)

I have another question..is there a way to update ContactKey using REST API?

Answer (score 2):

**Short Answer:**

You cant "update" the contact key.

**Explanation:**

This serves as a permanent record for your contact and is persisted in the system even after the contact is deleted. For email studio, I have seen instances where you can engage Support for a "Subscriber Key Migration". Since it SubscriberKey has the same function in Email Studio, I would suggest contacting Support to see if this can be done.

Comment: Thank you! When you say that persist in the system even after the contact is deleted you mean that if I delete a contact using REST API, it remains in the system? and If I bought 1M of contacts in my account, it's counted?

Comment: No. It wont count towards your billing / contact numbers, but the ContactKey will still be kept in the back end records.

Comment: Even this doesn't work? The doc says you update contact information

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/updateContacts.htm